# google api search results displaying from json format to php/html

Tags: php, json, api, google-api, google-api-php-client

I want to display the actvivites posts results which i recieved through goole json api url on my website, therefore i used following codeings. but its not displaying results. please advice
.

```
    <?php
   $jsonurl = "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities?orderBy=recent&query=%23fifa&alt=json&key={API KEY }";
    $json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);

    $json_output = json_encode($json);
    //echo json_encode($json);
    echo '<pre>';
    //echo json_encode($json);
    print_r($json_output);
    echo '</pre>';
    ?>
    <div class="datagrid ">


    <?php
    $json=array();
    foreach ($json_output["data"] as $json_result) {
        $json[] = array(
            'value' => $json_result["title"],
            'value' => $json_result["url"]

        );

      ?>

    <div ><table>


    <tbody>

        <TR>
        <TD><h3><?php echo $json_result["title"];?></h3></TD>
         <TD><h3><?php echo $json_result["url"];?></h3></TD>
        </TR>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>

      <?php

    }


    ?>

    </div>
```

[google api source](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/search#examples)

Comment: You're missing the closing `}` for the foreach

Comment: so what does your echo & print_r statements show

Comment: @user574632 : it gives 'false'

Comment: @ExplosionPills: it was there, just not indented properly for code formatting.

Comment: if you get false, then file_get_contents FAILED and returned a boolean false.

Answer (score 1):

I can point out a few things in your code. Some definitely need a little help.

You have these two lines.

```
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
```

$json is already a json encoded string,  I presume instead of the following line.  You actually want to decode it into an array.

```
$json_output = json_encode($json);
```

Such as

$json_output = json_decode($json, true);

notice I used the true parameter to make sure it gets all the way decoded instead of an array of std class variables. but I suppose it would depend on what you want in your code.